# Visual Studio C# - Window Form notification

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, visual-studio

I would like to make a popup notification. However, i dont want to use NuGet Tulpep notification. I would like to build one using a Form. The form will display only the latest data from Server just using one form instead of Multiple win-Form stacked together.

The problem i'm facing now is that, I created a dummy button (to represent incoming message) to create & Show Form 2 (as it look like pop out message).

In my popupnotificationbtn_Click:

```
  FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
  Form2 frm2 = new Form2();

  if(fc.Count < 2){
     frm2.Show();
     frm2.Location = new Point(screenwidth - frm2.Width, screenheight - frm2.Height);
     frm2.form2label.Text = "There is (" + (fc.Count - 1).ToString() + ") new complaint(s)";
  }
 else{
     frm2.Location = new Point(screenwidth - frm2.Width, screenheight - frm2.Height);
     frm2.form2label.Text = "There is (" + (fc.Count - 1).ToString() + ") new complaint(s)";
  }
```

Everytime i clicked the popupnotificationbutton, the label in the Form 2 does not update to latest integer(fc.Count -1).

So i decided to put the

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(),
```

outside of the `popupnotification_Click`, this works well.

However, when i close Form2 and reopen again, it crashed. Because the

```
frm2.Show()
```

in `popupnotification_Click` doesnt know which Form to show as it had closed already.

Comment: `So i decided to put the outside of...` well decide to put it back then. :)

Comment: I suggest 2 options: 1 provide the value of the integer as a parameter of the Popup Form and construct a new instance every time you need it. Or 2: Create a method in the Popup Class to set the value on the popup object. And call that within the Click method of the button.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve your error:

```
private void frm2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            this.Hide();
        }
```

Instead of closing your form you simple hide it, so you can re-open again. However I strongly suggest to use [MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx)-es in yur case

Comment: Perhaps he has a valid reason not to use a MessageBox?

Comment: I can't disagree on that. This is why I tried to solve his error first and then suggested, and based on this:   frm2.form2label.Text = "There is (" + (fc.Count - 1).ToString() + ") new complaint(s)"; I thought a messagebox would be easier

Comment: Hi, sorry, the reason i'm doing this is because, I want the Form2 deliver the latest message from server, and display only one Form instead of multiple forms stacked together. I've edited my question-code.

Comment: Have you tried what I gave you as a solution? Because hiding the form does not close it and you won't get the error. And you can show the form again whenever you feel like it.

Comment: Hi Elis, it doesnt really solve my problem, i want only one Form2 act as Message Notification Box that showing latest data from Server, instead of multiple Form appear on the screen.

The solution u reply is for hide() the Form only. I want only one form appear and showing latest data.